# How to insert the same UUID in two rows of two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, uuid

I try next script:

```
// Insert data into mysql 

$qry="INSERT INTO $tbl_name1 (ID, REFERENCE, CODE, NAME) VALUES (UUID(), '$REFERENCE', '$CODE', '$NAME')";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

$qry2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2 (PRODUCT) VALUES ('$ID')"; <--- Here is a problem
$result=mysql_query($qry2)
```

I do not know how two insert **the same UUID** in two tables simultanoiusly. Please help me!
I will appreciate much your support!

DONE!!!
THE WORKING SCRIPT:

```
$q = "SELECT UUID() AS uid";
$res = mysql_query($q) or die('q error: '.mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

// Insert data into mysql 
$qry="INSERT INTO $tbl_name1 (ID, REFERENCE, CODE, NAME) VALUES ('".$row['uid']."', '$REFERENCE', '$CODE', '$NAME')";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die('err 034r '.mysql_error());

$qry2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2 (PRODUCT) VALUES ('".$row['uid']."')";
$result=mysql_query($qry2) or die('gg2345  '.mysql_error());
```

Comment: why are you not using an auto incremented id - like every one else does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `SELECT UUID()` before you send the `INSERT`s and put the values into the statements in PHP. Something like this (untested):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT UUID() AS UUID") or die('SQL error: ' . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$UUID = $row["UUID"];

$qry="INSERT INTO $tbl_name1 (ID, REFERENCE, CODE, NAME) VALUES ('$UUID', '$REFERENCE',   '$CODE', '$NAME')";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

$qry2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2 (PRODUCT) VALUES ('$UUID ')"; <--- Here is a problem
$result=mysql_query($qry2)
```

Another way would be the use of a user-defined variable ([see SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9584/1)):

```
SET @UUID = (SELECT UUID() AS UUID);
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(@UUID, "foo");
INSERT INTO test1 VALUES(@UUID, "bar");
```

Comment: The problem that UUID is automatically associated during INSERT... I do not think it can be selected before INSERT

Comment: @SergiuCostas: `SELECT UUID()` is a valid SQL statement in MySQL. It should give you one UUID which you can use for your inserts. Another solution would be a user defined variable - see `@UUID` in my example. This would be my preferred way, since it would not require you to access the UUID from PHP at any time.

Comment: TBK - your answer was close to the right way....
The working script is next:

$q = "SELECT UUID() AS uid";
$res = mysql_query($q) or die('q error: '.mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

// Insert data into mysql 
$qry="INSERT INTO $tbl_name1 (ID, REFERENCE, CODE, NAME) VALUES ('".$row['uid']."', '$REFERENCE', '$CODE', '$NAME')";
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die('err 034r '.mysql_error());

$qry2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2 (PRODUCT) VALUES ('".$row['uid']."')";
$result=mysql_query($qry2) or die('gg2345  '.mysql_error());

Comment: Great, congratulations on getting it working. I fixed the answer, since I had a typo in it (missed a `$` in front of `row`, it must be `$UUID = $row["UUID"]`).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `ID` is the table Unique Index you could add before `$qry2`:

```
$ID = mysql_insert_id();
```