# Generate and Join UUID keys of two tables (SQL)

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, uuid

I'm building a simple database in MySQLWorkbench with two tables: Study (1) and Series (2). In the future, we will import data from a CSV file into these tables.

Study should generate a new UUID as PRIMARY KEY (PK) named `ID` for every new row.
Subsequently, Series should generate a new UUID as PK named `ID` for every new row.

Lastly, Series should generate a Foreign Key (FK) `StudyID`, with the same UUID's as the `Study` table column `ID`, so that these two tables can be joined on UUID for the ascending rows.

I found topics on stack with a somewhat similar question, but this didn't solve my problem:
[How to insert the same UUID in two rows of two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175462/how-to-insert-the-same-uuid-in-two-rows-of-two-different-tables)

[Best practices on primary key, auto-increment, and UUID in RDBMs and SQL databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414414/best-practices-on-primary-key-auto-increment-and-uuid-in-rdbms-and-sql-databas)

Could anyone give me a push in the right direction?

My code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `analog_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `analog_db` ;

 
CREATE TABLE Study (`ID` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT (UUID()),
                    `Number` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );


CREATE TABLE Series (`ID` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT (UUID()),
                     `Number` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, 
                     `StudyID` VARCHAR(36) DEFAULT (UUID()), 
                     PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
                     KEY `FK_StudyID` (`StudyID`),  
                     CONSTRAINT `FK_StudyID` FOREIGN KEY (`StudyID`) REFERENCES `Study` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION );
```